# Tomcat load-balancing with mod_jk

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

Newbie to this technology hence pls be gentle. Aim is to setup Tomcat load-balancing with mod_jk.
My setup is below (all on one machine):

Win7 x64
Apache Httpd 2.2
Tomcat 6
mod_jk 1.2.37 (for httpd2.2.x)
2 Tomcat instances (same machine)

I've setup Tomcat correctly and can access the webapps via localhost:8080 and localhost:8081.
But when I try to access the webapps via Httpd (localhost/dept1 or localhost/dept2), I get  "404 Not Found " The requested URL /dept1 was not found on this server.
Httpd works when accessed by URL, http: //localhost  "It works!"

The only lines added to httpd.conf (Apache2.2) are:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile C:/ApacheHTTPD/conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile C:/ApacheHTTPD/logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel emerg
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat +ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T %p %q %r %v %U"
JkMount /%CATALINA_HOME%/webapps/dept1/* tomcatbase
JkMount /%CATALINA_HOME2%/webapps/dept2/* tomcat1
```

workers.properties file contains:

```
worker.list=tomcatbase,tomcat1
worker.tomcatbase.type=ajp13
worker.tomcatbase.host=localhost
worker.tomcatbase.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
worker.tomcat1.port=8010
```

All other setup is (Apache and the 2 Tomcat instances) are default.
Now, http:// localhost:8080/dept1 works. So is it that the redirect from Apache to Tomcat isn't working?

Thanks in advance
Bharath

Comment: Off topic but I would have a good look at mod_proxy and mod_proxy_balancer. It does the same thing and it is orders of magnitude easier to set up.

Comment: thanks. I will try and understand mod_proxy/balancer also. I'm trying to get a hang around all these now since I'm working on learning load-balancers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
JkMount /dept1/* tomcatbase
JkMount /dept2/* tomcat1
```

The first parameter of the JkMount directive is a URL prefix, not a local path.

```
JkMount [URL prefix] [Worker name]
```

Please see http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html for more details.

Comment: that helped! thank you! I removed the "/" in JkMount "/dept1/*" so that when I type just localhost/dept1 I get the web application. So this means Apache gets the path of the webapps from Tomcat via the AJP port redirection. Is that correct? I'm trying to understand how the whole thing ties together.I'm reading online as well but sometimes basic hands on setup gives a clearer picture.

Comment: No, mod_jk does not get the path of the webapps. It redirects requests to the Tomcat's ajp port. BTW, [this blog post](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/06/16/deciding-between-modjk-modproxyhttp-and-modproxyajp) may help you to learn difference between mod_jk and mod_proxy_xxx.